# Ruby UTF-16 encoding I think

Tags: ruby, windows, encoding, popen3, utf-16le

I have a Ruby program  running on Windows which calls a shell command (which is known to output UTF-16) using Open3:

```
attrs={}
attrs[:stdout], attrs[:stderr], status = Open3.capture3(command)

unless attrs[:stderr].nil?
  begin
    attrs[:stderr].force_encoding(Encoding::UTF_16LE).encode!(Encoding::UTF_8)
  rescue => e
    attrs[:stderr] = attrs[:stderr].bytes.to_json.encode!(Encoding::UTF_8)
  end
end
```

If the force_encoding to UTF_16LE doesn't work, and throws an exception, I simply save the bytes, encode it as a JSON string and encode it as UTF_8.

Well....the exception was thrown and I caught the output array of bytes in the rescue clause. It looks like this:

```
[10,84,104,105,115,32,97,112,112,108,105,99,97,116,105,111,110,32,104,97,115,32,114,101,113,117,101,115,116,101,100,32,116,104,101,32,82,117,110,116,105,109,101,32,116,111,32,116,101,114,109,105,110,97,116,101,32,105,116,32,105,110,32,97,110,32,117,110,117,115,117,97,108,32,119,97,121,46,10,80,108,101,97,115,101,32,99,111,110,116,97,99,116,32,116,104,101,32,97,112,112,108,105,99,97,116,105,111,110,39,115,32,115,117,112,112,111,114,116,32,116,101,97,109,32,102,111,114,32,109,111,114,101,32,105,110,102,111,114,109,97,116,105,111,110,46,10]
```

How can I convert it back to text in some format. e.g. If I do:

```
irb> "dog".bytes
=> [100, 111, 103]
irb> "कुत्रा".bytes
=> [224, 164, 149, 224, 165, 129, 224, 164, 164, 224, 165, 141, 224, 164, 176, 224, 164, 190]
```

Is there a way to programmatically convert [100, 111, 103] to "dog" or [224, 164, 149, 224, 165, 129, 224, 164, 164, 224, 165, 141, 224, 164, 176, 224, 164, 190] back to "कुत्रा" ? And is there a way to figure out what my output array of bytes means?

-------------------------  UPDATE ---------------------------

I dug around a bit, but it took a while, because "decode" is not a thing. However, I did the following with the array which I held in the variable **message**:

```
message.map{|c| c.chr}.join("")

=> "\nThis application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.\nPlease contact the application's support team for more information.\n"
```

So my problem is solved, in that the error message is not in UTF-16LE.

However, when I did this, I got the result which follows:

```
irb> "कुत्रा".bytes.map{|c| c.chr}.join("")

=> "\xE0\xA4\x95\xE0\xA5\x81\xE0\xA4\xA4\xE0\xA5\x8D\xE0\xA4\xB0\xE0\xA4\xBE"
```

How do I convert this strange looking string or byte sequence into the more meaningful "कुत्रा" ?

Comment: Did I answer you updated question question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering your first question about the bytes, take a look at the Pack method in array: [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#pack-method).

```
[100, 111, 103].pack('U*') # Returns 'dog'.
```

The 'U*' formating tries to match in the bytes array as many UTF8 characters as possible.

If you use that method in your error message you get:

```
"\nThis application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.\nPlease contact the application's support team for more information.\n"
```

------------------------- UPDATE ---------------------------

Just noticed you figured the first part out and added a new question.

> How do I convert this strange looking string or byte sequence into the
>   more meaningful "कुत्रा" ?

When you execute `"string".bytes.map{|c| c.chr}.join("")` the bytes on the new string are the same, but the encoding is lost. This can be seen here:

```
s = "dog"
s.encoding #=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
s = "dog".bytes.map{|c| c.chr}.join("") #=> "dog"
s.encoding #=> #<Encoding:US-ASCII>
```

This has the expected effect with strings like 'dog', because UTF-8 is backwards compatible with ASCII-8BIT, this means that string that use only ASCII-8BIT characters will work in UTF-8. But with characters that use more than 1 byte in UTF-8, like '€', they are not recognized in ASCII. So, to answer you question, what you need to do is force the appropriate encoding on the string, like this:

```
"कुत्रा".bytes.map{|c| c.chr}.join("").force_encoding('UTF-8') #=> "कुत्रा"
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Worth mentioning -- `U` indicates UTF-*8*, not UTF-16/UCS2. If you were actually dealing with UTF-16, something like this might be appropriate (not tested): `bytes.map(&:chr).join.force_encoding(Encoding::UTF_16)`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to programmatically convert [100, 111, 103] to "dog"?

[Array#pack](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-pack)

```
pry(main)> "dog".bytes.pack('c*')
=> "dog"
```

For the other letters, try the same or "कुत्रा".bytes.pack('U*').
I can't use those Marathi (Ehh It also means 'dog' lol) in my pc

> How do I convert this strange looking string or byte sequence into the more meaningful "कुत्रा" ?

```
pry(main)> p "कुत्रा".bytes.map{|c| c.chr}.join("")
=> "\xE0\xA4\x95\xE0\xA5\x81\xE0\xA4\xA4\xE0\xA5\x8D\xE0\xA4\xB0\xE0\xA4\xBE"

pry(main)> puts "कुत्रा".bytes.map{|c| c.chr}.join("")
=> कुत्रा
```

Which is basically:

```
puts "\xE0\xA4\x95\xE0\xA5\x81\xE0\xA4\xA4\xE0\xA5\x8D\xE0\xA4\xB0\xE0\xA4\xBE"
```